# connection between android and database

Tags: php, android, database-connection

May I know what is the problem of this http connection?
I get the "HTTP Problem" when run this.

```
public void makeHttpPost(){
    try
     {
         //http post
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/project/login.php");              
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();        
         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namevaluepairs));
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
         is = entity.getContent();
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"HTTP PROBLEM",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
}
```

Comment: can u logcat? and is ur php url running on brower?

Comment: this is the error show-->android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
the php url cn run

Comment: ok thats mean u r running ur php url in OnCreate rather than that u need Async Task that will help you .. m post one answer check that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Call the below class where u hv called makeHttpPost()
>    Call this class as below :

```
    new LoadData().execute();


    class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         // ur http code
            makeHttpPost();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);



    }
}
```

Comment: Can I know where to add the buffer() and login() ?

Comment: i think u r buffering after login right? if yes the fire login url first in doInBackground method and the fire the url for buffering

Comment: I directly buffer() and login() right after makeHttpPost()
the buffer() here mean to convert result of php to string

Comment: ok call ur login method in doInBackground method and ur buffer method in onPostExecute method of the above class

Comment: for the loaddata class, i need to extends the mainactivity class there only cn directly use the makeHttpPost() right?

Comment: see u need to place this class in ur activty directly .. do not extend anything ..

Comment: but when i directly put in my mainactivity, the new LoadData().execute() there show error

Comment: chat somewhere i can explain u better

Comment: just like where? u suggest~